# Apache で PHP を動作させたいが、ソースコードがそのまま表示されてしまう

Tags: php, centos, apache

CentOS7のサーバーで、PHPのWEBアプリケーションをapacheで動かそうとしています。

現在、apacheでPHPが動いていないので、対象のパスにアクセスすると、PHPが動作しておらず、
ソースコードがそのまま表示されています。

新規設定ファイルとして、

```
LoadModule phpModule modules/libphp5.so
```

を追加しました。該当ファイルはシンボリックリンクですが存在しています。

```
$ systemctl restart httpd
```

すると、

```
Job for httpd.service failed. See 'systemctl status httpd.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

となります。

```
$ journalctl -axn
```

すると、

```
 4月 18 13:15:27 tomato.centostkg httpd[2478]: httpd: Syntax error on line 56 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/php.conf: Cannot load modules/libphp5.so into server: libgmp.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 4月 18 13:15:27 tomato.centostkg systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 4月 18 13:15:27 tomato.centostkg kill[2480]: kill: cannot find process ""
 4月 18 13:15:27 tomato.centostkg systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
 4月 18 13:15:27 tomato.centostkg systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

となっています。
PHPはうまくinstallできなかったので、ソースから再ビルドしました。
libgmp.so.10を/usr/lib/libgmp.so.3にシンボリックリンクを作ればいいとのことだったのですが、それも試してうまくいきませんでした。

Comment: パッケージマネージャでうまくインストールできないのであれば、まずそちらの解決を試みた方がよいのではないでしょうか。具体的な問題が示されていないので何とも言えませんが、環境が何かおかしな状態になっている可能性もあります。

Comment: 冷静にいったんapacheとphpを削除して、一からインストールしてapache再起動したらうまく動きました。
なんだかよくわかりませんね。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

直接の原因は分かりませんが、いったん Apache と PHP を削除して、一からインストールし直して
Apache を再起動したらうまく動きました。

---

*この投稿は [@omarun さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9280/apache%e3%81%aephp%e7%92%b0%e5%a2%83%e6%a7%8b%e7%af%89#comment8391_9280) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*